# Concat and loading several files

Tags: python, dataframe, import-from-excel

I have the following code (posted here, Import multiple excel files into python pandas and concatenate them into one dataframe) and try to use it but it keeps flagging the following error:

> BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

I do not have any zip file in my directory.  The only files are Jupyter notebooks, Excel files.

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("C:/Users/rmerida/OneDrive/Mineco/Unidad Inteligencia Mercados/Mesa Inversión Interinstitucional/Hitech/*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)

all_data.to_xls("Consolidado.xlsx")
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xlsx` file is a kind of zip file. This error sometimes happens depending on a version of Python or modules.

Following code could sovle the problem, by explicitly specifiy an engine to read an excel file.

```py
df = pd.read_excel(f, engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: @user17743486 Does it answer your question?